# How to convert my thoughts in OOP to Haskell?

Tags: haskell

For example, I have a container type to hold elements with common character. And I also provide some types to be the element. And I also want this function to be easily extended (others could make their own element type and be hold by my container).

So I do:

```
class ElementClass
data E1 = E1 String
instance ElementClass E1
data E2 = E2 Int
instance ElementClass E2
data Element = forall e. (ElementClass e) => Element e
data Container = Container [Element]
```

This is fine until I need to deal with the element individually. Due to forall, function "f :: Element -> IO ()" has no way to know what element it is exactly.

What is the proper way to do this in Haskell style?

Comment: Please give a more descriptive title to your question

Comment: Well... what operations do you want to be able to do on elements?

Comment: You should skip the forall and don't bother with the Element class, then parameterise the container data structure on the element type. data Container e = Container [e]

Comment: you have to stop thinking OOP and start thinking FP - meaning thing about the operations not about the data (that is - put the *character*  in a record or something and just use a list (or whatever collection) of these records instead of trying to simulate OOP

Comment: Add `f` to the class, so that in the instances you can define the behaviour for any type inside that class. Or, better, add some other primitive operations to the class so that it is possible to implement `f` afterwards just using such primitives.

Comment: @DanielWagner, read the data contained in each element.

Comment: @AndrewC, then a Container will hold only one type, right? I want it to hold any types that could work as ElementClass.

Comment: @CarstenKönig, yes, that is what I was thinking. But I really cannot come up with a solution.

Comment: @chi, that is an idea. Let me see if it works.

Comment: @Magicloud Why? Other than reimplement OOP or disable the type system or forget forever what your data was, why is this useful? The proper way to do this in Haskell style is _not_ to mix all your data types together.

Comment: What every OOP programmer should read if they're tempted to do this in Haskell: Luke Palmer's [Haskell Antipattern: Existential Typeclass](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/). Here's the logic: with an existential typeclass (or equivalent GADT), the programmer has lost any ability to recover the original type, and can only deal with the data via the typeclass functions. It's _much_ easier to simply pass these functions around as a record than mess with the type system while storing the original data. Functions are easy to manipulate in Haskell

Comment: @AndrewC, with "data Container e = Container [e]", if e is not a wrapper of ElementClass, based on the original code, once it is constructed as "Container [3 :: Int]", this container will only contain Int, right?

Comment: You'd not be able to mix types together except by means of a tagged union, so `Container [3,7,4]` would be a different type to `Container [True,False,True]`, and you couldn't do `Container [3,'h',False]`, but could do `data MyTaggedUnion = AnInt Int | ABool Bool | AChar Char` and then `Container [AnInt 3, AChar 'h', ABool False]`. My question was why you needed to mix types together.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58423/discussion-between-magicloud-and-andrewc).

Answer (score 7):

> to know what element it is exactly

To know that, you should of course use a simple ADT

```
data Element' = E1Element E1
              | E2Element E2
              | ...
```

this way, you can pattern-match on which one it is in your container.

Now, that clashes with

> others could make their own element type and be hold by my container

*and it must clash*! When other people are allowed to add new types to the list of elements, there's no way to safely match all possible cases. So if you want to match, the only correct thing is to have a closed set of possibilities, as an ADT gives you.

OTOH, with an existential like you originally had in mind, the class of allowed types is open. That's ok, but only because the exact type isn't in fact accessible but only the common interface defined by `forall e. ElementClass e`.

Existentials are indeed a bit frowned-upon in Haskell, because they are so OO-ish. But sometimes this is quite the right thing to do, your application might be a good case.

Comment: The existential type class anti-pattern.  Rarely, it is truly what you want.  Often you can do without the type class.  Sometimes (esp. considering laziness), you can also do without the existential.

Comment: I think it's unlikely an OOP programmer new to Haskell has hit upon the rare cases that this is a good plan, and much more likely they're unused to the functional paradigm and are just trying to do it like they did it before. Without more functional guidance they tend to conclude in frustration that their new aeroplane is stupidly difficult to manoeuvre round the car park.

Comment: Thank you. I thought this before, and discarded due to inexpandable. So it is clear that this is the only way.

Answer (score 6):

Ok I'll try to help a bit.

First: I assume you have these data types:

```
data E1 = E1 String
data E2 = E2 Int
```

And you have a sensible operation on both that I'll call `say`:

```
say1 :: E1 -> String -> String
say1 (E1 s) msg = msg ++ s

say2 :: E2 -> String -> String
say2 (E2 i) msg = msg ++ show i
```

So what you can do without any type-classes or stuff is this:

```
type Messanger = String -> String
```

and instead of having a container with lot's of `E1` and `E2`, instead use a container with `Messagner`s:

```
sayHello :: [Messanger] -> String
sayHello = map ($ "Hello, ")

sayHello [say1 (E1 "World"), say2 (E2 42)]
> ["Hello, World","Hello, 42"]
```

I hope this helps you a bit - the thing is just going away from the object and looking at the operations instead.

So instead of pushing the objects/data to a function that should work with the objects data and behaviour just use a common "interface" to do your stuff.

If you give me some better example of *classes* and *methods* (for example two types that might indeed share some traits or behaviour - `String` and `Int` are really lacking on this) I will update my answer.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, make sure you read and understand ["Haskell Antipattern: Existential Typeclass"](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/).  Your example code is more complex than it needs to be.

Basically, you're asking how to perform the equivalent of a downcast in Haskell—cast a value from a supertype to a subtype.  This sort of operation can intrinsically fail, so the type is something like `Element -> Maybe E1`.

The first question to ask here is: do you really need to?  There are two complementary alternatives to this.  First: you can formulate your "supertype" in such a way that it only ever has a finite, fixed number of "subtypes."  Then you implement your type just as a union:

```
data Element = E1 String | E2 Int
```

And every time you want to use an `Element` you pattern match and presto, you have the case-specific data:

```
processElement :: Element -> whatever
processElement (E1 str) = ...
processElement (E2 i) = ...
```

The downsides to this approach are that:

1. Your union type can only have a fixed set of subcases.
2. Every time you add a subcase you will have to modify all the existing operations to add an extra matching case for it.

The upsides are:

1. By enumerating all the subcases in your type, you can use the compiler to tell you when you've missed one.
2. Adding a new operation is easy, and doesn't require you to modify any existing code.

The second way you can go is to reformulate the type as an "interface".  By this I mean your type is now going to be modeled as a record type, each of whose fields constitutes a "method":

```
data Element = Element { say :: String }

-- A "constructor" for your first subcase
makeE1 :: String -> Element
makeE1 str = Element str

-- A "constructor" for your second subcase
makeE2 :: Int -> Element
makeE2 i = Element (show i)
```

This has the upside that you now can have as many subcases as you want, and you can easily add them without modifying existing operations.  It has these two downsides:

1. If you need to add new operations, you will have to add a "method" (field) to the `Element` type, and modify every existing function that constructs an `Element`.
2. Consumers of the `Element` type can never tell which subcase they're dealing with, or get information specific to this subcase.  E.g., a consumer can't tell a particular `Element` started was constructed with `makeE2`, much less extract the `Int` that such an `Element` encapsulates.

(Note that your example with existentials is equivalent to this "interface" approach, and shares the same advantages and limitations.  It's just needlessly verbose.)

But if you really insist on having the equivalent of a downcast, there is a third alternative: use the [`Data.Dynamic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Dynamic.html) module.  A `Dynamic` value is an immutable container that holds a single value of any type that instantiates the `Typeable` class (which GHC can derive for you).  Example:

```
data E1 = E1 String deriving Typeable
data E2 = E2 Int deriving Typeable

newtype Element = Element Dynamic

makeE1 :: String -> Element
makeE1 str = Element (toDyn (E1 str))

makeE2 :: Int -> Element
makeE2 i = Element (toDyn (E2 i))

-- Cast an Element to E1
toE1 :: Element -> Maybe E1
toE1 (Element dyn) = fromDynamic dyn

-- Cast an Element to E2
toE2 :: Element -> Maybe E2
toE2 (Element dyn) = fromDynamic dyn

-- Cast an Element to whichever type the context expects
fromElement :: Typeable a => Element -> Maybe a
fromElement (Element dyn) = fromDynamic dyn
```

This is the closest solution to the OOP downcasting operation.  The downside to this is that downcasts are inherently not type safe.  Let's go back to the case where, some months later, you need to add an `E3` subcase to your code.  Well, the problem now is you have a lot of functions sprinkled throughout the code that are testing whether an `Element` is an `E1` or an `E2`, which were written before `E3` ever existed.  How many of these functions will break when you add this third subcase?  Good luck, because the compiler has no way of helping you!

Note that this three-alternative scenario I've described also exists in OOP, with these three alternatives:

1. The OOP counterpart to union type is the Visitor pattern, which is meant to make it easy to add new operations to a type without having to modify its subclasses.  (Well, relatively easy.  The Visitor pattern is hella verbose.)
2. The OOP counterpart to the "interface" solution is to code 100% to an interface (or abstract class).  This means not only that you use an interface—it also means that your client code **never** "peeks under the interface" to see what the actual implementation classes are; it relies entirely on the interface methods and their contracts.
3. The OOP counterpart to the `Dynamic` solution is to use downcasting.  It has the same downsides as I explained above—somebody can come in and add a new subclass, and code that "peeks" at the runtime subtype may not be ready to handle this.

So to the broader question of how to change from OOP thinking to Haskell thinking, I think this comparison provides a good starting point.  OOP and Haskell provide all three alternatives.  OOP makes #3 very easy, but that basically gives you rope to hang yourself with; #2 is what many OOP gurus would recommend you do, and it can be achieved if you are disciplined; but #1 in OOP gets very verbose.  Haskell makes #1 easiest; #2 is not much harder to implement, but requires more careful forethought ("am I providing the correct operations for all users of this type?"); #3 is the one that's a bit verbose and against the grain of the language.